# To find which of the following statistics is (are) sufficient but NOT complete

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,....X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with the probability density function

$$f(x|\theta) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{\theta^2}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}},  & \text{if $x>0$; $\theta>0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Which of the following statistics is(are) sufficient but NOT complete?

$A=\bar X$

$B=\bar X^2+3$

$C=( X_1,\sum_{i=2}^{n}X_i) $

$D=(X_1,\bar X)$

**My input**

The joint probability density function of the sample is

$f(x_1,x_3,x_2...x_n|\theta) =\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\theta^{2n}}\bigg(e^{\dfrac{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\theta}}\bigg)$

Let $T(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$  .We see that the pdf can be expressed as a function that depends on the sample only through $T(x)$. Thus $T(x)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$

$A$=  is sufficient statistic because $\bar X$ is a function of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$
by dividing the whole sum by $n$ gives $\bar X$ ( I am not sure if this reasoning of mine is valid I just can't explain it to someone in brief. I need a perfect reasoning for that so someone tell me that.)

$B$= is a sufficient statistic because any one to one function of sufficient statistic T is also sufficient statistic. For example, if $x>0$ $x^2$ will be a one to one function.

$C$= Sum of these two statistics give $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$

$D$= I am not sure how to calculate sufficient statistic in this one because I am not able to derive $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ with any linear combination. So my intuition says it's not sufficient statistics.

Completeness is the next step but I am stuck in calculating sufficient statistic.
I am learning these concepts  so please give me any tips ,advice before calculating these things.

Comment: Since A is a statistic of D, A being a sufficient statistic means D is too.  You have  $0 \cdot X_1 +n \cdot \bar{X} = \sum_i X_i$

Comment: @Henry My reasoning for B is valid ?

Comment: In this case, I am convinced by B, since here $\bar X \ge 0$ with probability $1$.  But that might not be the case in other problems

Comment: Since $\sum X_i$ (and hence $\overline X$) is a complete sufficient statistic, I think you can rule out (A) and (B) from the options. (D) is a sufficient statistic, since $(\overline X,T)$ is a sufficient statistic for any other statistic $T$; not sure about completeness of (D).

Comment: @StubbornAtom E($X_1)=2\theta$, E($\bar X)=2\theta$ 

Let $g(T)= X_1-\bar X$,

E($X_1-\bar X) = 0 $ ,

doesn't mean $g(T) = 0$ $\implies $  Not complete. Am I right?

Comment: Oh yes, $E(X_1-\overline X)$ is always zero. So (D) is one possible answer.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Oh yes! silly me I went thoroughly. 
Also for $C$ , E($X_1)=2\theta$, E($\sum_{i=2}^{n}X_i)=(n-1)2\theta$ 
,
Let $g(T)= (n-1)X_1-\sum_{i=2}^{n}X_i$,

$E((n-1)X_1-\sum_{i=2}^{n}X_i) = 0 $ ,

doesn't mean $g(T) = 0$ $\implies $  Not complete.

Comment: Looks good. Well done. What about sufficiency of C?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I mentioned in my question. Their sum equals to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i $. Which implies they are sufficient.